# Function getImage(); not displaying images on website.

Tags: php, sql

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I have a function to call
and display images from my database, they are not loading for me.

Here is my code below:

```
 <?php
            $itemQuery = "SELECT title, description, price, location FROM item;";
            $returnItemQuery = (mysqli_query($conn, $itemQuery));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($returnItemQuery) > 0) {

                    function getimage() {
                    include("connection.php");                  
                    $imageQuery = "SELECT image FROM item";
                    $image_info = (mysqli_query($imageQuery));

                    while ($image_data = mysqli_fetch_array($image_info)) {

                    echo $image_data['image'];  
                    }
                    }

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($returnItemQuery)) {
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $location = $row['location'];


                    echo "                                     
                    <img src='$image'width='auto' height='auto'>
                    <br> Title: $title</br>
                    <br> Description : $description</br>
                    <br> Price: $price</br>
                    <br> Location: $location</br>";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

I have a table called 'item' with image saved as a mediumBlob. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance provided!

Comment: Why did you wrap that code in `function getimage() { ... }`?  Just get rid of that.

Comment: All sorted, forgive me, im new.